# add a tag LIMITED QUANTITY to products in Magento community 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, products, tags, product-tag

kindly note i have a selective products around 20 that i need to show a label or a tag " LIMITED QUANTITY". i tried the add tag under catalog but its only related to back end and administrator use and not to front end use. can anyone help me how to make this enable on website front end?
thanks in advance for help and support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new product attribute and assign the **LIMITED QUANTITIES** value to all required products:

1. In the admin, create a new `product attribute` by navigating to **Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes**, and clicking **Add New Attribute**. Call the new attribute something like `limited_qty_message`.
2. The new attribute should be of type `Text Field`.
3. Add this new text field attribute to **EVERY ATTRIBUTE SET** that contains the products that you need to assign the **LIMITED QUANTITIES** value.
4. Set the value of this new attribute for your 20 products as **LIMITED QUANTITIES**.

Now output this new value, if it's set, to the product page:

1. Open `/app/design/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` in your text editor.
2. Paste the following code in the file *where* you would like to output the new attribute:

```
<?php if ($_product->getData("limited_qty_message")) : //if the attribute has a value for this product ?>
    <?php echo $_product->getData("limited_qty_message"); // output it's value ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Once the attribute value is outputting as you need, add your HTML markup and style it.

Comment: dear kindly note i tried it today and after clearing magento cache and flushing my history and browsing cache on many browsers and devices; its showing on the backend of magento but not on the website front end. i set a text for 5 products for now for testing but they are not appearing on the website; can you help?

Comment: @Marcos - this definitely works. I would double check that you did not miss any of the steps. If it still doesn't work, I would enable template path hints, clear cache, and refresh your product page to confirm that you are working in the correct template file for the product details page.

Comment: this is my template path : /public_html/app/design/frontend/tv_arion_package/tv_arion/template/catalog/product/view.phtml and your code was added successfully in this file under product description section! although, keep in mind, i need to show the ribbon or the label in the listing page. shall i work on a different file or the same?

Comment: You would need to add the same code from above to the list template. `/public_html/app/design/frontend/tv_arion_package/tv_arion/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`. The code snippet would need to be added inside both `foreach` loops - once for the `list` view, and again once for the `grid` view.

Comment: OK dear i can see it now in the website but i have 2 store views. and its showing like a description and not a label or a tag on the image like i requested earlier in list view or grid view. i don't want it as description of the product but i want it as a tag or label. can i send you a clear screenshot or something related to be more specific please?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. This is the first time you've mentioned anything about an image.....please clarify. You asked how to output the information on the page, and it sounds like we have accomplished that with this answer. Are you referring to style? How to make it look more like a `ribbon` instead of plain text?

Comment: yes can you help me make it as ribbon and not plain text dear?

Comment: @Marcos - Yes, I can help, but please ask a new question for that since styling the output was not part of this original post/question. If my answer above assisted you in outputting the label to the front end, please mark it as the accepted solution. Then post a new question regarding styling it.

Comment: YES i accept the above answer and its already done you can check it. as for the style i need to make it as ribbon can you you help me make it out? or can i send you a screenshot to show you what i mean since i cannot add here?

Comment: @Marcos - Yes, I can help. Please post a new question. I'll watch for it. Include screenshots or anything else that may be helpful.

Comment: done: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246432/tag-a-limited-quantity-ribbon-or-label-in-listing-view-or-grid you can check it now please!